# facebook: Post to a user's wall AS the app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-wall, facebook-timeline

I would like to know if it is possible to post to a user's wall AS an app. So, my app would be interpreted like a user and writes on the wall of the target user. So far, I only found ways to post to a user's stream as himself with some information of my app attached.

Is this possible? If so, how ? (I am using the PHP and JS SDK)

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible but not advisable because Facebook is going to stop this method pretty soon. Basically your app can only publish to a user's own wall in the future.